# Excel chart : how to *not* scale to numeric values on X

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I would like a chart with dates on X, displaying those dates but not scaling to them

Here's a data table with values on Y and dates on X

```
Date          Value
2016-10-01    10
2016-10-02    15
2016-12-01    10
```

When I ask excel for a chart ignoring the dates, I get the following chart, which is correct except it doesn't display dates on X legend:
[image]

If I add the dates as label for X axis, it automatically scales X to the dates, which I don't want:
[image]

How do you instruct excel to just use dates as display without scaling to it?

**Note:** Using Office 2013

**Note:** Using an extra column as "copy the dates as uninterpreted string" and using that column as X label is possible but painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set to interpret your dates as text in the axis, so no need for helper column:

Insert your chart (as in your second example), then right click horizontal axis - properties - then select "axis type" : "text axis"

[image]